# how to redirect to other ejs from script of one ejs file with arguments

Tags: javascript, server

i created a room using socket.io and want to send the meassage from one ejs file to the other

```
    function joinRoom() {
        let roomCode = document.getElementById('roomCode').value;
        if (roomCode) {
          console.log(roomCode);
          socket.emit("pvt-room",roomCode);
          roomCode="";
        }
      }

      socket.on("pvt-msg",(msg)=>{
        window.location.href = '/chat';
      })
```

here is the server side code

```
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.render("room.ejs");
    });

    app.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
      res.render("chat.ejs");

    });

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("a user connected");
      socket.on("pvt-room", (roomNo) => {
      socket.join(roomNo);
       io.to(roomNo).emit("pvt-msg", "welcome to private room");
     });
   });
```

i tried sending the data from one ejs file to the other ejs file through the script tag of the first ejs file. But not able to parse the url data at the server side